# Confused about metrics

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have some odd metrics that I need clarified.

My reputation on the "Where does the signal know where the cable ends and antenna starts is a +4 meanwhile the answer I posted has a -2 votes. So what is up?

However, my reputation points for the screechy fuzzy signal question has 3 up votes but a -2 reputation.

What kind of a twilight zone episode did I just check into?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the "How does the signal know where the cable ends and antenna starts" answer has an upvote and three downvotes. That should give you a nett +4 (+10 for the upvote and -2 for each downvote).

The "Screechy fuzzy signal" question has four upvotes and one downvote. That gets you a nett 18 points (+5 for each upvote, and -2 for the downvote).

So it's not the Twilight Zone, just basic mathematics.

This information came from the ["What's Reputation" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).